# Setting decimal in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a decimal field and when I convert the string '1000,00' to decimal on my machine with SQL Server in portuguese it saves correctly 1000 but at the server, where the OS is in english, it saves 100000.

I've already set the regional settings to portuguese and the database collation to Latin1_General_CI_AS.

What I failed to do on the server?

Comment: that is because you have a comma and not a period.  In English a period is used to specify the whole number from the fractional part of a number.  So, a string of `1000.00` would convert to 1000.

Comment: Would you please do this select in for example Management Studio and report the result: `select @@language`

Answer (score 1):

You should transfer it between the computers as a `decimal` (or other appropriate number type) and store is as a numeric type, if possible, not a `string`. If you do need to use a `string` at all, use the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) where appropriate to convert to and from the number type, to avoid locale errors like this.

In short, the culture of the server should never come into play: you should make it fixed.

Comment: I used invariant culture and it worked, thank you.

Convert.ToDecimal(valor, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));